# Create remote admin user on multiple macs script

Tags: macos, bash, sh, remote-access

so I'm trying to create a script and add an admin user to multiple macs possibly using ARD. I have tried my below script individually and it has worked but when I send a UNIX command through ARD to a mac it doesn't entirely work and I can't login with newly created account (maybe something up with my password??). I do see the admin account's folder created but that's about it. What do you guys suggest. NOTE: at the end of the script I have part of the code commented out which I will test to hide the account if the initial creation of the account works.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script creates a user account under Mac OS X

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats UserShell /bin/bash

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats RealName "ThunderCats"

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats UniqueID 627

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats PrimaryGroupID 1000

sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/ThunderCats

sudo dscl . passwd /Users/ThunderCats randompwd

sudo dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership ThunderCats

sudo cp -R /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj /Users/ThunderCats

sudo chown -R ThunderCats:staff /Users/ThunderCats

#sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats IsHidden 1

#sudo dscl . create /Users/ThunderCats IsHidden 0

#sudo mv /Users/ThunderCats /var/ThunderCats

#sudo dscl . -create /Users/ThunderCats NFSHomeDirectory /var/ThunderCats

echo "Created user" #$USERID: $USERNAME ($FULLNAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to grant ARD rights.
something like this:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a ThunderCats admin
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users hiddenadmin -privs -all -restart -agent
```

or

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users admin -privs -all -restart -agent -menu
```

Answer (score 0):

or 
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users admin -privs -all -restart -agent -menu